# google charts - when single row chart is zoomed out

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I have a chart with a single row
`{"cols":[{"id":"time","label":"Time","type":"datetime"},{"id":"Value","label":"Value","type":"number"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"Date(2018,7,31, 14, 49, 48, 0)"}]}]}`. When I view the chart on my screen I am present with a "zoomed out" version. I much rather have something that would be "zoomed in" with correct date displayed on the axis. How can this be achieved?

I have tried `hAxis.viewWindowMode: 'pretty'` with no luck.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `hAxis.viewWindow.min` & `max` to set the range of the axis.
and `hAxis.ticks` to control which axis label(s) appear.

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages:['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable({
    "cols":[
      {"id":"time","label":"Time","type":"datetime"},
      {"id":"Value","label":"Value","type":"number"},
      {"id":"Value","label":"Value","type":"number"},
      {"id":"Value","label":"Value","type":"number"},
      {"id":"Value","label":"Value","type":"number"},
      {"id":"Value","label":"Value","type":"number"},
    ],
    "rows":[
      {"c":[{"v":"Date(2018,7,31, 14, 49, 48, 0)"}, {"v": 50}, {"v": 31}, {"v": 16}, {"v": 14}, {"v": 5}]}
    ]
  });

  var dateRange = data.getColumnRange(0);

  var options = {
    chartArea: {
      height: '100%',
      width: '100%',
      top: 24,
      right: 16,
      bottom: 60,
      left: 60
    },
    hAxis: {
      format: 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss',
      viewWindow: {
        min: new Date(dateRange.min.getFullYear(), dateRange.min.getMonth(), dateRange.min.getDate() - 30),
        max: new Date(dateRange.max.getFullYear(), dateRange.max.getMonth(), dateRange.max.getDate() + 30)
      },
      ticks: data.getDistinctValues(0),
      title: 'Time'
    },
    vAxis: {
      ticks: [0, 15, 30, 45, 60]
    },
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: It did help, I didn't think about `getColumnRange()`